# Prestashop 1.7 Webservice API. POST order_invoice with lines

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

So I've noticed we can create order invoices using Prestashop Webservice:

POST /api/order_invoices/&ws_key=1111111111H1573D8SC1NNN000000 HTTP/1.1

**Request body:**

```
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <order_invoice>
    <id><![CDATA[33022]]></id>
    <id_order><![CDATA[44517]]></id_order>
    <number><![CDATA[1232132166]]></number>
        <total_discount_tax_excl>
            <![CDATA[0.000000]]>
        </total_discount_tax_excl>
        <total_discount_tax_incl>
            <![CDATA[0.000000]]>
        </total_discount_tax_incl>
        <total_paid_tax_excl>
            <![CDATA[434.580000]]>
        </total_paid_tax_excl>
        <total_paid_tax_incl>
            <![CDATA[465.000000]]>
        </total_paid_tax_incl>
        <total_products>
            <![CDATA[434.580000]]>
        </total_products>
        <total_products_wt>
            <![CDATA[465.000000]]>
        </total_products_wt>
        <total_shipping_tax_excl>
            <![CDATA[0.000000]]>
        </total_shipping_tax_excl>
        <total_shipping_tax_incl>
            <![CDATA[0.000000]]>
        </total_shipping_tax_incl>
        <shipping_tax_computation_method>
            <![CDATA[0]]>
        </shipping_tax_computation_method>
        <total_wrapping_tax_excl>
            <![CDATA[0.000000]]>
        </total_wrapping_tax_excl>
        <total_wrapping_tax_incl>
            <![CDATA[0.000000]]>
        </total_wrapping_tax_incl>
    <shop_address><![CDATA[]]></shop_address>
    <note><![CDATA[]]></note>
    <date_add><![CDATA[]]></date_add>
  </order_invoice>
</prestashop>
```

The issue is that this created a Invoice linked to the order, but only with Totals. The products in the order are not shown in the printed (PDF) Invoice.

Is there any way we can create the Invoice with the Invoice Lines using the API?

Comment: Does this resolve your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76381590/how-i-can-download-invoice-file-by-api-in-prestashop/76392189#76392189. If you want to use the web-service API have a look in the documentation on what is available, for example ´Order Slip´: https://devdocs.prestashop-project.org/1.7/webservice/resources/order_slip/